# Wordpress: How to get the tag's slug on the tag page

Tags: wordpress, tags, slug

I'm on the tag.php page. How can I get its slug?

`single_tag_title()` gets the title just fine, but the slug?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can get the slug by getting the queried object while on the tag page, like so:

```
<?php
    $tag = get_queried_object();
    echo $tag->slug
?>
```